# How to properly refresh a ListView from another class by using Socket.io?

Tags: java, android, listview, nullpointerexception, socket.io

I tried writing a simple chat with socket.io for android.
My code below works, but I'm not sure whether I need a static method because for a ListView field and MyBaseAdapter class I'm getting the following message:

> Do not place Android context classes in static fields; this is a memory leak

If I change that to non-static, I get this error message:

> MyBaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()' on a null object reference

Below is my code:

```
package com.example.seadog.fb_dialog;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import io.socket.emitter.Emitter;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Emitter.Listener {

    private static ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();

    private static ListView listView;
    private static MyBaseAdapter adapter;

    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SocketIo socketIo = new SocketIo(this);

        if(socketIo.getSocket()==null) {
            socketIo.Connection();
        }

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        adapter = new MyBaseAdapter(this, arrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Intent newActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Conversation.class);
                startActivity(newActivity);

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void call(Object... args) {

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

}
```

below is my SocketIo class code:

```
package com.example.seadog.fb_dialog;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import io.socket.client.Ack;
import io.socket.client.IO;
import io.socket.client.Socket;
import io.socket.emitter.Emitter;

public class SocketIo {

    private static Socket mSocket = null;
    private Emitter.Listener messageListener;

    private String API_BASE_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:3030";

    private Integer id = 654864;     // Website ID
    private Integer userId = 6522;   // UserID

    private String jwt;

    public SocketIo(Emitter.Listener messageListener) {
        this.messageListener = messageListener;
    }

    public void Connection() {

        try {
            mSocket = IO.socket(API_BASE_URL);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {

            /*
             * Join to default a room after connect
             */

            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {

                // create json object and join to room (Website ID)
                // ...more code, not important here

            }

        }).on("jwt", new Emitter.Listener() {

            /*
             * Get a token and find all active conversations
             */

            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {

                // get a token as args
                jwt = args[0].toString();

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

                try {
                    jsonObject.put("token", jwt);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // find active conversations
                mSocket.emit("messages::find", jsonObject, new Ack() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Object... args) {

                        String response = args[args.length - 1].toString();

                        try {

                            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

                            for (int i = jsonArray.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

                                // create JSON object and add to arrayList

                                mainActivity.setArrayList(ld);

                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                });

            }

        }).on("message", new Emitter.Listener() {

            /*
             * Message Listener
             */

            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {

                String message = null;

                try {
                    JSONObject object = (JSONObject) args[0];

                    // Create here JSON Object and add to JSON Array

                    mainActivity.setArrayList(ld);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                String finalMessage = message;

                //mainActivity.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

        }).on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {

            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
            }

        });

        mSocket.connect();

    }

    public Integer getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public Socket getSocket(){
        return mSocket;
    }

}
```

Comment: What other class? Static variables are certainly not the solution here

Comment: I try refresh listview by Socket.io Listener when it return a new data. MyBaseAdapter class is custom LayoutInflater.

Comment: An adapter isn't a layout inflater, try getting the terminologies correct.

Answer (score 1):

Break your code up into MVP pattern.
Write a Presenter, that is directly tied to your Activity. The Presenter is used to wrap calls to Libraries, Frameworks etc. that are needed for your I/O, Database stuff and so on.

The Presenter may fullfill an Interface

```
void onData(ListData data);
```

Instead of calling your activity directly, call your Presenter. He will cache your data, transform it as it's needed for your Activity and our Activity may have a function, that is exposed via an interface like

```
void displayListItems(List<ListDataViewModel> viewModels);
```

If the Activity / Presenter will be closed, try implementing a Repository, that is storing the data to a local database, so you can restore them.

Answer (score 0):

First, change everything back to non static

Make your Activity implement `Emitter.Listener` (or define a interface yourself of a similar nature)

Pass that interface as a parameter to your SocketIO class (assuming you can edit it)

From within the call method you'll have to implement, you call non-static methods to update the list

Assuming you `implements Emitter.Listener`, within the SocketIO class, use the listener that you put as a parameter for the message action

```
.on("message", this.messageListener)
```

**Example**

First, add a parameter to SocketIO

```
private Emitter.Listener messageListener;
public SocketIO(Emitter.Listener messageListener) {
    this.messageListener = messageListener;
}
```

Then, update your activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Emitter.Listener {

    private ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();

    private ListView listView;
    private MyBaseAdapter adapter;

    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SocketIo socketIo = new SocketIo(this);  // Pass the interface parameter
        adapter = new MyBaseAdapter(this, arrayList);

        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void call(Object... args) {

       ... // TODO: parse out args

       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

---

If you instead defined your own interface,

```
.on("message", new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(Object... args) {

        String message = null;
        //  TODO parse your message... 

        // don't update the adapter here, do it where you implement this interface 
        if (messageListener != null) {
            messageListener.onMessageReceived(message);
        } 
    }
```

Of course, pick your own naming conventions and variable types

Comment: I do not know if I described it well. I use Socket.io for android. My SocketIo class only connect to server and it listener. Main Activity is in MainActivity class where is listview which I want update when SocketIo class and more specifically: ".on("message"... return a new data. From a SocketIo class I want refresh my listview within MainActivity class. I don't know how to use your example. I do not want to mix these two classes because I have now clear code.

Comment: You have "clear" code, but it is not functional, right? You also do not want to "couple" your SocketIO class to your Activity. That is messy code. The "clean code" approach is to *use interfaces / listeners / callbacks*

Comment: I used your code but something is wrong. I updated my question. Look that, please.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to this problem would be to use a [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) that you create on the main (UI) thread. Pass a reference into you Emitter.Listener listener and when you want your ListView to be updated you can package the data you received in the listener in to a [Message](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html) and send it to be received by the [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) that you created on the main (UI) thread. When you receive the data in the handler's [handleMessage()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#handleMessage(android.os.Message)) you extract it from the [Message](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html) object the method takes as an parameter and update your adapter and then call notifyDataSetChanged which will always be called on the UI thread when data is received.

(Fun note, the Handler/Message system is used throughout the Android SDK to perform work asynchronously and then pass the results to the main (UI) thread).

Absolutely do not create static reference to activities, fragments, views because they can hold a reference to owning activity and inadvertently leak the entire activity and all of its view elements on an innocuously of a situation as single rotation. For example your ListView object is a view element that internally holds into a context from its owning activity, one rotation the android system will destroy the activity and attempt to GC it, but can't because an unreachable object holds a reference to it.

```
package com.example.seadog.fb_dialog;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Handler.Callback {

    private ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();

    private ListView listView;
    private MyBaseAdapter adapter;

    private TextView textView;
    private Handler mHandler;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Pass in a reference to ourself so that we can get messages on the UI thread in the handleMessage below.
        // Since onCreate is called on the main (UI) thread, the handler will also get created on the same thread.
        mHandler = new Handler(this);

        SocketIo socketIo = new SocketIo();

        if(socketIo.getSocket()==null) {
            socketIo.Connection();
        }

        // Pass in a reference to our handler.
        socketIo.on("message", new MyEmitter(mHandler));

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        adapter = new MyBaseAdapter(this, arrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Intent newActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Conversation.class);
                startActivity(newActivity);

            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // THIS GETS CALLED ON THE MAIN (UI) THREAD.
        // Since you are only sending once Message at a time you don't have to worry about handling others.
        Bundle bndl = msg.getData();
        ListData data = bndl.getParcelable("ListData");     
        // I assume this method exist on your adapter class if not, use what every method you want to add a new set of data.
        adapter.addListData(data);
        // At this point you just need to tell the adapter that it's dataset has changed and should update the listview.

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();     
        return true;
    }


    private static class MyEmitter extends Emitter.Listener {

        private WeakReference<Handler> mHandler;
        public MyEmitter(Handler handler) {
            mHandler = new WeakReference<Handler>(handler);
        }

        public void call(Object.. args) {
            Handler handler = mHandler.get();
            // The handler is stored in a week reference so that this listener doesn't
            // improperly hold on to it and prevent it from getting GC'd.
            if(handler != null) {               
                try {
                    JSONObject object = (JSONObject) args[0];
                    String message = null; = object.getString("message");
                    // You will need to make this class parcelable.. I deliberately left this out.
                    ListData ld = new ListData();
                    ld.setID(1);
                    ld.setTitle("Klient:");
                    ld.setDescription(message);                 
                    // Get a message object that will be sent to the activities handler.
                    Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
                    Bundle bndl msg.getData();
                    bndl.putParcelable("ListData", ld);
                    // This will send the message to the activities handler on the UI thread. The handleMessage will get called.
                    msg.sendToTarget();

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

This code will need some small changes but the general idea is all there.

Comment: Can you show me simple example? I don't know how can I do it.

Comment: Thank you but I'll tell you honestly that I don't understand your code. I don't understand implements, handler and listener in android yet. A code of @cricket_007 is for me better more understandable but his code yet not works properly too.

Comment: @SeaDog 'implements' is a key construct in an OO language such as Java. It simply means that the Activity above will provide an implementation for the methods define in an interface. "Handler.Callback" is an interface with the one method "handleMethod".
Handler is simply a mechanism for receiving a Message object. The listener pattern isn't unique to Android, or Java. It's an language agnostic method of subscribing for data when it's variable.
I think you maybe in over your head a bit and would definitely benefit first learning OOP with the Java language and then Android development.

Comment: I'm not a beginner in programming but I still have a lot to learn, especially in object-oriented programming. Thanks for the explanation.